# Base for iterating over git history

Tags: python, git

I wanted to do some statistics over the history of a Git repository. At first I tried using GitPython, but it wasn't as trivial as I imagined it to be. In the end, I just call the necessary git commands with the submodule module.

Can this code be considered clean and readable or does it have some style issues?

```
import argparse
import os
import subprocess

def main(args):
    if not os.path.isdir(args.path):
        print "not a directory"
        return
    if ".git" not in os.listdir(args.path):
        print "not a repo"
        return

    os.chdir(args.path)

    commitIDs = []
    start = 0       #load commits in batches, to avoid too long hangs
    max_count = 100
    while True:
        text = subprocess.check_output(["git", "rev-list", args.branch, "--max-count=%s" % max_count, "--skip=%s" % start])
        start += max_count
        for line in text.splitlines():
            commitIDs.append(line)
        #print "loaded", len(commits), "commits"
        if len(text.splitlines()) != max_count:
            break

    for commitID in commitIDs[::-args.skip]:    #start with the oldest commit
        print commitID
        #do something with the commit
        #for example:
        #devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        #subprocess.call(["git", "checkout", commitID], stdout=devnull)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('path', nargs="?", default=".")
    parser.add_argument('--branch', '-b', default="master")
    parser.add_argument('--skip', '-s', type=int, default=1, help='use every n-th commit')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

Update:

```
import argparse
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import git

def main(args):
    try:
        repo = git.Repo(args.path)
    except:
        sys.exit("no such repo")

    try:
        text = repo.git.rev_list(args.branch).splitlines()
    except:
        sys.exit("no such branch")

    commit_ids = text[::args.skip]

    print "loaded %s commits" % len(commit_ids)

    for commit_id in commit_ids[::-1]:  #start with the oldest commit
        print commit_id
        #do something with the commit
        #for example:
        #repo.git.checkout(commit_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('path', nargs="?", default=".")
    parser.add_argument('--branch', '-b', default="master")
    parser.add_argument('--skip', '-s', type=int, default=1, help='use every n-th commit')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Great, glad you got rid of that loop: some more things I'd like to point out. As this is essentially another question now I'll add another answer

1. I don't think a function should call `sys.exit()`. I'd rather you raised an exception instead and call `sys.exit()` in `__main__`

   I.e. instead of:

   ```
   try:
       repo = git.Repo(args.path)
   except:
       sys.exit("no such repo")
   ```

   I would prefer:

   ```
   from git import Repo, InvalidGitRepositoryError
   #...

   try:
       repo = git.Repo(args.path)
   except InvalidGitRepositoryError, e:
       raise InvalidGitRepositoryError("%s is not a git repository" % (str(e)))
   ```

   This enables other Python classes to use your `main` function (which is a terrible name) in a more predictable way (Python doesn't close calling your function).
2. I would also rather you check for the branch than assume if `rev-list` gives an error that the branch doesn't exist. There may be some other case that causes it to throw an exception.

   ```
   class InvalidBranchError(Exception):
       pass

   if args.branch not in repo.branches:
      raise InvalidBranchError("Branch does not exist: %s" % (args.branch))
   ```
3. Instead of `main` taking an arguments parser, I would prefer you used regular arguments (again so other python modules can use your code more readily):

   ```
   def main(path=".", branch="master"):
      pass

   main(path=args.path, branch=args.branch)
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I will work on it tomorrow. On the note of the main function, I just thought that passing args object to the function isn't a good idea too as it makes it harder to call it manually.

Comment: And about the first point, I'm not sure if I get it, your suggested code raises pretty much the same error, so what's the difference between not handling it at all and seeing `git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError: C:\ ` and handling to see `git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError: C:\ is not a git repository ` ?

Comment: I figured in `__main__` you would catch exceptions and do `sys.exit( str(exception) )` so adding some details may be useful if you decided to use that approach

Answer (score 3):

You actually can access the *commit_id* with GitPython methods via the `hexsha` attribute. Short example:

```
import git

def main():
    repo = git.Repo('.')
    for commit in repo.iter_commits('master'):        
        # do something with the commit, for example:
        repo.git.diff(commit.parents[0].hexsha, commit.hexsha)  
        # commit.committed_datetime.strftime("%a %d. %b %Y")
        # commit.message.rstrip() 

        # see http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-commit-object for more information on the available attributes/methods of the commit object
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The goal of the site is to provide value by reviewing the code in the question.  Can you explain how your answer improves upon the original question?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I wasn't aware that. Basically this is a very short answer to following sentence form the original question: 'At first I tried using GitPython, but it wasn't as trivial as I imagined it to be.' I didn't have the time to fully rewrite the code, but thought might profit if I share my 'solution'.

Answer (score 2):

A few small comments:

- I would suggest to use exit codes (`sys.exit()`), it will help you if you are planning to  you your script together with other scripts (chaining it, or use from shell scripts)
- I would consider that `subprocess.check_output(["git", "rev-list...` may return not a list of commits (but error for example). In this case you may go to infinite loop.
- Usually you can execute git commands from any subfolder of a git repo. In your case you are limiting it to be a root folder by using this condition `if ".git" not in os.listdir(args.path)`
- Instead of `for line in text.splitlines(): commitIDs.append(line)`, do `commitIDs.extend(text.splitlines())`
- You execute `text.splitlines()` twice, consider creating a temporary variable for it
- You are constructing a huge list first and use `args.skip` on it. Instead you can apply `args.skip` inside your `while` loop. It will limit amound of memory you need.
- `commitIDs` => `commit_ids`

Comment: Your advice about commitIDs.extend() and moving args.skip inside the white loop seem to conflict with each other. The only way I think could implement this is by a non trivial list comprehension inside extend(). Any hints for this one?

Comment: they don't necessary conflict `commits = text.splitlines()[::args.skip]`, `commitIDs.extend(commits)`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't keep skip state between batches if batch size is not divisible by skip - if you have two batches of size 4: [0, 1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6, 7] and skip 3 in the end you should get [0, 3, 6], while your approach would give [0, 3, 4, 7].

Comment: Actually, @megawac is right, loading everything in one go is not a problem at all as it turns out. I was being too cautious.

Comment: Ya, I would be tempted to file a git bug if you ran into a case where your loop method was faster than calling revlist once